# marionette childViewContainer - Can it have two child containers

Tags: marionette

As per my requirement I need to show two different sets of data into two different child containers.

For Example:

**ItemView**

```
var itemView = new Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template : "<%=id%><%=name%>",
    model : Model,
    tagName: "tr"
});
```

**CompositeView**

```
Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    childView : itemView,
    childViewContainer : "table.employee-table.new",
    template : below html template
});
```

**Html Template:**

```
<div>
    <table class="employee-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="new"></tbody>
        <tbody class="old"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I want to group old employees into the old (class="old") table body and new employees grouped into new (class="new") table body.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried doing it with 2 containers, but with 2 different views in the same collection, you can do it, by overriding ***getChildView*** function in Marionette.CompositeView

```
class Notifications extends Marionette.CompositeView
    template: require './templates/player_notifications'
    childView : Notification
    childViewContainer : "#caption"
    modelEvents:
        "sync" : "render"
    getChildView: (item) ->
        if (item.get('type') == "notification:payment")
            PaymentNotification
        else if (item.get('type') == "notification:player:connected")
            PlayerConnectedNotification
        else if (item.get('type') == "notification:player:discovered")
            PlayerDiscoveredNotification
        else
            Notification

class Notification extends Marionette.ItemView
    template: require './templates/player_notification'

class PaymentNotification extends Marionette.ItemView
    template: require './templates/payment_notification'

class PlayerConnectedNotification extends Marionette.ItemView
    template: require './templates/player_connected'

class PlayerDiscoveredNotification extends Marionette.ItemView
    template: require './templates/player_discovered'
```

In the same way there is a ***getChildViewContainer*** function in Marionette.CompositeView, which you can override.

Or just split your collection in 2 on fetch in your Backbone.Collection.